# different size vectors errors for map2 funciton

Tags: r

I am trying to implement parallel processing to make the `STEPAIC` function running on several models more efficient.

I've came into some errors, like vectors differing in length.

This is my code:

```
library(MASS)
library(furrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(prediction)

nb_thesis_inter <- function (df,mdl){ 
  target_col <- "mpg"
  interactions<- predictors(mdl)
  target_formula <- as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ (%s)^2", 
                                       target_col, 
                                       paste(interactions, collapse = " + ")))
  model <- MASS::glm.nb(target_formula, data = df)
  model <- (MASS::stepAIC(model))
  return (model)}


m<- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest()
m<- m %>% mutate(model= map(.x = data, .f =  ~lm(mpg ~ .)))
m<- m %>% 
  mutate(model= future_map2(.x= data, .y=model, .f = nb_thesis_inter))
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the dlay, I edited the code and added libraries.. Can you share your code?

Comment: This is now returning Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `model`.